# Javascript confirm dialog in iOS UIWebView freezes app

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, confirm

I have an iOS app which has a `UIWebView` in which I have a `javascript` opening a `javascript` confirm dialog. Once this opens the app "freezes". It's not completly frozen, the debugger says everything is fine, rotating the screen will work once, then not anymore. But most importantly I just can't confirm the dialog or do anything else.

I can't really give code for that. It's just a `javascript` confirmation box called like this

```
 if(!confirm('String')) return;
```

Does anyone have an idea where this could come from? I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, had you found out what was causing this?

Comment: Hey, Nop - never found a fix, but I guess if you look into my other answers you can see how I called functions within iOS from JS ... se the easiest would probably be to write quicker wrapper for IOS-Alerts and make a call to this form JS instead of using alert.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I had the alert/confirm dialog inside of an onchange event. The solution was to wrap the code containing the alert/confirm statements inside a setTimeout function.

Comment: This worked for me too. I wonder how this behavior fits into Javascript's single thread model and what exactly happens behind the scenes.